# Analog and Digital Output protection?

Tags: protection, output

I know it's important to protect analog and digital inputs. My question is should you also protect outputs, both analog and digital?

For the inputs, right now I'm using [clamping diodes](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/index.php/Diodes_and_Transistors#Voltage_Clamp,), an MOV, a series resistor, and a series ferrite bead for high frequency noise rejection.

If outputs should be protected, how should this protection differ from inputs?

Comment: Kind of depends on the system requirements.  Short-circuit protection on an output is pretty common.  If the output is likely to be shorted to a potentially destructive voltage then you might want to protect against that too.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to protect outputs from?

Comment: A couple of things... ESD, any voltage on the line that shouldn't be there, (and short circuit perhaps based on John D's comment). Anything I'm forgetting?

Comment: Really anything that will fry or interfere with the microcontroller and MOSFETs it's driving.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it will depend on your system and it's requirements. It's up to you to evaluate your system and its intended use and decide whether or not to include the protection. Here are some examples of things to consider:

Arguments for Protection:

1. User Error
   Users can find wonderful and borderline magical ways to plug things in incorrectly, so adding protections to every electrical connection that the users have access to will make your device more robust. This is especially a concern in consumer electronics which have a lot of users that aren't very technologically sophisticated (or who have children).
2. ESD
   As mentioned in the comments, even properly used devices that aren't always grounded can build up a static charge that can damage your device.
3. What is the output driving?
   If you have an analog output driving an inductive load (such as a simple DC motor or solenoid) you have to protect against [inductive kick](http://www.coilgun.info/theoryinductors/inductivekickback.htm) and [Back EMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force). If your device is subject to these kinds of events during normal operation, protecting your outputs isn't really an option.
4. Other
   There is always the chance that unexpected conditions may damage a device, even if users are doing the correct thing and ESD isn't a concern. For example, consider an audio mixer (which are always grounded). Even if an expert plugs all the cables in the right way, there may be two worn out cables in a bundle of 30 of them that causes two outputs to be shorted together. If they drive at different voltages, one of those two outputs is going to be very unhappy if it's left unprotected.

I'm going to bundle the arguments against additional protections into one group, because they're pretty much the same as any other electronics projects: increasing the number of components increases design and validation time and complexity, all kinds of costs, and board and packaging size.

In the end, you have to balance the level of protection required for your product against the various costs associated with implementing those protections.

It's hard to answer your second question without a specific application in mind. For some low voltage analog and digital outputs, a simple diode placed in series with your output may be sufficient. Other situations may require more complex protections like an RC or diode snubber for inductive loads. It just depends on your application.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do need the protection. I'm just not sure of the best circuit to accomplish it. Mostly we're dealing with DC voltage inputs for the digital inputs. Analog inputs are 0-10V or 4-20mA.

Comment: Outputs are MOSFETs being used as an open drain output. Max voltage/current fore each channel is 36V and 1A. Gate is being driven directly by microcontroller digital output pin.

Comment: That's a lot of good detail, but I think you should open a new question with it. I like your current question and think it stands on its own as a good question for general guidance. Opening a new question with as many details about your specific case as you can obtain should net you some good advice. Unfortunately, I haven't done enough design work at those voltage and current levels to be able to offer you any more detailed help with that.